# Update a Joomla 1.5 module to Joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I know how to create a module for Joomla 1.6. But I have heard that it's possible to add a set of Joomla 1.5 parameters and a set of Joomla 1.6 parameters in the same XML installation file to make only one package compatible with 1.6 and 1.5. I tried this trick but the XML file isn't valid.

Can you give an example of a XML file compatible with Joomla 1.5 and Joomla 1.6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to make a module compatible with Joomla 1.5 and Joomla 1.6.

In XML installation file:

1. Insert the tag install (`<install type="module" version="1.5.0">`)
2. Include Joomla 1.5 parameters. Example:
   `<params>

   <param type="radio" name="autoplay" default="0" label="autoplay">

       <option value="1">JTRUE</option>

       <option value="0">JFALSE</option>

   </param>

   </params>`
3. Include Joomla 1.6 parameters. Example:
   `<config>

   <fields name="params">

           <fieldset name="basic">

           <field type="radio" name="autoplay" default="0" label="autoplay">

               <option value="1">JTRUE</option>

               <option value="0">JFALSE</option>

           </field>

               </fieldset>

        </fields>

   </config>`

Then, update your Joomla 1.5 language files to work on Joomla 1.6. Joomla 1.6 files can be used in Joomla 1.5. See [http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files][1]

[1]: Specification of language files